# Is there a single composite standardized instrument to measure Diversity, Equity, and Inclusion at workplace (DEI)?

Tags: untagged

Is there a single composite standardized instrument to measure Diversity, Equity, and Inclusion at workplace (DEI)? can you please share if it is available.

Comment: Social psychologists do occasionally study diversity, identity, discrimination, training, and efficacy, but workplace DEI sounds like an organizational performance measure rather than anything to do with psychology, so I tend to agree that this is better suited for workplace.SE.

Comment: A [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=standardized+equipment+to+measure+Diversity%2C+Equity%2C+and+Inclusion) reveals hundreds of results, most of them ([1](https://www.mckinsey.com/featured-insights/mckinsey-explainers/what-is-diversity-equity-and-inclusion) - [2](https://heller.brandeis.edu/iere/pdfs/dei-organizational-assessment-tools.pdf)) use metrics of the same standards, with differences linked to the field of activities. Some sell [tools](https://www.sopact.com/dei-dashboard). There seem to be no *standardized* instrument of measure like you define it, so check by yourself?

Comment: A universally accepted single Composite Standardized Measurement of Diversity, Equity, and Inclusion in the Workplace would certainly rank among the top ten clear and present dangers to the continued existence of our Republic.

Comment: DEI is relative to the locale. My company is 95% Asians, because we're in an Asian country. It'll be VERY odd to replicate this demographic somewhere else, like in Spain.

Comment: thank you for all your suggestions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires that there be a governing body responsible for defining these standards for which there is not.

Answer (score 5):

Is there a single composite standardized instrument to measure Diversity, Equity, and Inclusion at workplace (DEI)?

No.